# Set Java VM maximum memory size

Tags: java, c++, memory

I've small Linux server (VPS) with 1GB of RAM i want to give Java VM only 256MB
is there an option to limit Java VM to that memory size, so when I excede that limit I start to catch OutOfMemory Exception

The main problem that when load exceed on memroy I shall return overload error, and this is an accepted reponse, but the problem Java keeps going eating system memory that shall be free for other programs by force!!

Yes, I need to minimize the memory, because the Server is not dedicated for Java only and exceeding memory for the sack of Java is not an option.

and if there is no Java option that way, shall I go for C++ for linux develpment, complixety, threading or memory management is not a problem since this Java program is just a dedicated service

Comment: -Xmx256m is the option.

Comment: Its a big secret, but Oracle actually does provide documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html . what isn't a secret is the thousands of links google provides when you search for "java memory configuration" or any variant thereof.

Comment: Also, don't try catch OutOfMemory exceptions (acually an error). It's very unlikely you will be able to recover from it.

Comment: actually I use small program, and Java goes up, the idea is simple, don't exceed you share of memeory, which i can't inforce by any means! trying this sample java -Xms1M -Xmx1M -Xss1M -jar program.jar must give error by theory, but no Java has minimum memory about 64M, it is ok, then I shall have 191MB, it goes up!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can control Java's heap size when you launch it with the `-Xmx` parameter. In your case, this would be `-Xmx256m`.

Answer (score 0):

The option you need is `-Xmx256m`.

Reading from JVM's documentation

> -Xmx [g|G|m|M|k|K]  This option sets the maximum Java heap size. The Java heap (the “heap”) is the part of the memory where blocks of
>   memory are allocated to objects and freed during garbage collection.
>   Depending upon the kind of operating system you are running, the
>   maximum value you can set for the Java heap can vary.

Comment: Try this command shall throw OutOfMemeroy error <br/> java -Xms1M -Xmx1M -Xss1M -jar program.jar <br/> no free -m shows system used more over 60 MB of memeory and release it after killing Java VM !!